# Are raisins considered one of the seven species for the purposes of prioritising brachot?

Tags: blessing, food, fruits

When prioritising brachot (for example before eating a fruit and nut mix) are raisins still considered one of the seven species, being made from grapes?

Comment: "Made from grapes" is a weird characterization of raisins. They _are_ grapes. Why would you think they wouldn't count?

Comment: Paranoia I suppose. :) I've always assumed they are simply dried and not altered in any other way but suddenly wondered if I was right about that.

Comment: You would make Al Haeitz. The only issue may be that you'd need to eat more of them given that drying them makes them smaller so you need to eat more to make up a k'zayis.

Answer (score 7):

Raisins are grapes and are treated the same. That is, since you know the location of grapes in the order of precedence (one of the seven species and where grapes fall in that list) then the position of raisins is the same.

I am showing the bracha acharona for raisins to show that they are treated exactly the same as grapes as far as being one of the seven species. The bracha Rishona of Haeitz would not prove that point.

[The Various Brocha Achrona 's](http://berachot.org/halacha/15_brachaachrona.html)

> 4. Al Ha’etz
>
> 1) Is required when on eats a kazyit of fruit of the 7 specifies
>   (olives, dates, grapes, figs, and pomegranates) within 4 minutes.
>
> 2) All other fruits are borei nefashot. However if one ate a kazayit
>   of 7 species fruits and also ate some other fruits – only Al Ha’etz is
>   required, since it covers all fruits.
>
> 3) For example: If one ate a kzayit of raisins (dried grapes, which
>   are Al Ha'etz) and some oranges - he would only need to make an Al
>   Ha'etz which would cover BOTH the raisins and the oranges. If he also
>   ate some carrots (which grow fom the ground) he would need to make a
>   separate borei nefashot on the carrots becuase the Al Ha'etz can only
>   cover fruits that grow from trees, but not Ha'adoma items.

[Shivat HaMinim](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Order_of_Brachot)

> The order of having the Shivat HaMinim is 1)Olives 2)Dates 3)Grapes 4)
>   Figs 5)Pomegranates. When any of the five grains are cooked into
>   mezonot dishes they take precedence over the Shivat HaMinim because
>   the Bracha of Mezonot precedes HaEtz. Conversely, if the five grains
>   are eaten raw, the Bracha is HaAdama and it the Shivat HaMinim being
>   HaEtz take precedence to the HaAdama
>
> S”A 211:4 says that the order of the SHivat haMinim is according to
>   the proximity each food has to the word “Eretz” in the פסוק “ארץ חטה
>   ושערה וגפן ותאנה ורמון ארץ זית שמן ודבש:” (Devarim 8:8). The order is
>   judged by proximity (reading the פסוק in the forward direction) to
>   either word Eretz, and the first Eretz has precedence. Seemingly then
>   the order should be 1)Wheat (first to the first Eretz) 2) Olives
>   (first to the second Eretz) 3) Barley (second to the first Eretz) 4)
>   Dates(second to second Eretz) 5) Grapes (third to first Eretz) 6) Figs
>   (fourth to first Eretz) 7)Pomegranates (fifth to first Eretz).
>   However, the Mishna Brurah 211:25 concludes that barley (when cooked
>   into a dish) precedes olives since Mezonot always precedes HaEtz.
>   Additionally, S”A 211:5 writes that wheat and barley only take
>   precedence when they are cooked into a Mezonot dish, as opposed to
>   when they are eaten raw and require HaAdama. Mishna Brurah 211:27
>   rules that if one does eat wheat or other grains raw, since they are
>   HaAdama it comes after the other Shivat HaMinim which are HaEtz unless
>   the raw grain is one’s personal preference (like any HaAdama and
>   HaEtz).

Comment: You dont tell us which brocha achrona has to be made first or is there no difference.

Comment: @newcomer The general rule is the most specific bracha is made first.

Comment: well @sabbahillel which one do you consider more specific and why. One is not yotsai if you make one on the other are you.

Comment: @sabbahillel Isn't this question about order of precedence?

Comment: @DoubleAA I had read the question as whether ofr not raisins were treated as grapes or as having lost that status because of the processing. I rewrote the answer to prove they are the same as grapes and then give the order of precedence rule.

Comment: @newcomer I rewrote the answer to explicitly give the order of precedence after first proving that raisins are treated the same as grapes.

Comment: You dont tell us which brocha achrona has to be made first or is there no difference. – newcomer 12 hours ago . This is what I originally wrote. In your long answer I have not yet found the answer.

Comment: The order is the same as the order of the seven species. Is that what you mean? That is mezonos, gefen, eitz, followed by borei nefashos. Note, gefen is for drinking wine, eitz is for eating fruit.